# "Package Doesn't Exist" - Error if I try to include a JAR-File [java compiler]

Tags: java, jar, package, javac, javacompiler

My problem is the following:
I am sort of new to programming and I wanted to **include the *guava.jar* file** I found on the internet (to use the *ImmutableList.copyof()*-method). I also have **additional packages that I want to include** (I wrote a few classes that handles stuff that's relevant for the project).
I implemented the following structure:
**Location of the Main-Method that imports the AdditionalClass**:

```
src/com/chess/engine/Main.java
```

**The location of the AdditionalClass-method that imports the guava-jar** :

```
src/com/chess/engine/board/MyAdditionalClass.java
```

If I compile my project from the "src"-directory via `javac -cp com/guava.jar com/chess/engine/Main.java` and I get the following **error-message**:

```
com/chess/engine/Main.java:3: error: package com.chess.engine.board does not exist
import com.chess.engine.board.*;
^
```

I think that the problem is that I set the classpath to the *guava.jar* file and that's why the compiler suddenly doesn't find the `AdditionalClass` anymore, but I don't know how to change.
If I don't include `(...) -cd com/guava.jar (...)` and compile by using `java com/chess/engine/Main.java` the `AdditionalClass` will be recognized by the compiler but I get a bunch of new errors because the compiler can't find the *guava.jar* and therefore has no idea what to do with the `"ImmutableList.copyOf()"` method I implemented.

Comment: `java -cp com/guava.jar;. com/chess/engine/Main.java`

Comment: Could you briefly explain the command you posted? It gives some fundamental errors that I can't really resolve
`com/chess/engine/Main.java:1: command not found: package
com/chess/engine/Main.java:3: no matches found: com.chess.engine.board.*
com/chess/engine/Main.java:5: command not found: public
com/chess/engine/Main.java:6: unknown file attribute: i
com/chess/engine/Main.java:9: parse error near `}'`

Comment: I also tried `java -cp com/guava.jar:. com/chess/engine/Main.java ` with **:** instead of **;** (I read in another thread that it might be the problem), but then I am back to the same old error  `error: package com.chess.engine.board does not exist `

Comment: Linux? Path separator is `:`, so `java -cp com/guava.jar:. com/chess/engine/Main.java`.